# Download apps without Google account for work device

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

I need to set up an Android device for work. I've never done this before (for a work environment), so I was wondering: is there a way to use the Play Store (the new owner will probably need WhatsApp and other apps) without a Google account?

Should I make a new Google account for every device?

We don't use G Suite.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the app [Aurora](https://aurora-store.en.softonic.com/android). It's like the Play Store but better for your use case. I use it for Android 6 install on a tinker-board. You can even install apps as a guest (no account required).

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the Play Store you need a Google account. But you do not need to have separate accounts for each and every device. You can connect to many devices from one account. In this case, all you have to do is log out from your account and tell the other user to connect with their account. Then the user will be able to use WhatsApp, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign in to your Google account. Whether it is already signed in to another device or not, it doesn't matter.

But you can download applications from other websites. For example, I am providing you WhatsApp's download link below:

https://apkpure.com/whatsapp-messenger/com.whatsapp

The base URL is

https://apkpure.com/